# JavaScript - How to Remove quotation marks in object data

Tags: javascript, html, json

Here's my JSON :

```
var userDetailsObj = {
   data: {
      homesize: {
         id: "",
         details: ""
      },
      floors: {
         id: "",
         details: ""
      },
      internetPlan: {
         id: "",
         details: ""
      },
      devices: {
         id: "",
         details: ""
      },
   }
}
```

But when i try to print it in a **pre** tag, the quotation marks also gets printed.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group padded">
  <pre id="dataSummary1" style="margin-right: 0.5rem;" class="btn fnt-size btn-lg btn-outline-primary uniform-btns">
   </pre>
   <pre id="dataSummary2" class="btn cntr-text btn-lg btn-outline-primary uniform-btns">
   </pre>
</div>
<div class="btn-group padded">
   <pre id="dataSummary3" style="margin-right: 0.5rem;" class="btn cntr-text btn-lg btn-outline-primary uniform-btns">
   </pre>
   <pre id="dataSummary4" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary cntr-text uniform-btns">
   </pre>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
function replaceData(obj){
   document.getElementById('dataSummary1'). innerHTML = '<h4> ' + JSON.stringify(obj.data.homesize.details) + '</h4>';
```

.....
    }

Is there any way to remove the quotations?

EDIT: I'm talking about "".

Comment: What quotation marks? Is it in the text?

Comment: Oh, sorry if i was not clear. the " " ones

Comment: Oh, why are you stringifying a string? There is no reason for `JSON.stringify()`. Dump it and your `""` will magically go away.

Comment: oh, my god i was not supposed to stringify it! Thanks epascarello! Im new to javascript so i mostly get my materials online. Kudos!

Comment: Answer: My bad, was not supposed to stringify it since it's already a string. Thanks @epascarello!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `JSON.stringify(obj.data.homesize.details)` by `obj.data.homesize.details`

```js
var userDetailsObj = {
  data: {
    homesize: {
      id: "",
      details: "Hi"
    },
    floors: {
      id: "",
      details: ""
    },
    internetPlan: {
      id: "",
      details: ""
    },
    devices: {
      id: "",
      details: ""
    },
  }
}

function replaceData(obj) {
  document.getElementById('dataSummary1').innerHTML = '<h4> ' + obj.data.homesize.details + '</h4>';
}

replaceData(userDetailsObj);
```

```html
<div class="btn-group padded">
  <pre id="dataSummary1" style="margin-right: 0.5rem;" class="btn fnt-size btn-lg btn-outline-primary uniform-btns">
   </pre>
  <pre id="dataSummary2" class="btn cntr-text btn-lg btn-outline-primary uniform-btns">
   </pre>
</div>
<div class="btn-group padded">
  <pre id="dataSummary3" style="margin-right: 0.5rem;" class="btn cntr-text btn-lg btn-outline-primary uniform-btns">
   </pre>
  <pre id="dataSummary4" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary cntr-text uniform-btns">
   </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call `replace` after `stringify`:

```
JSON.stringify(userDetailsObj).replace(/"/g,'')

//yields: "{data:{homesize:{id:,details:},floors:{id:,details:},internetPlan:{id:,details:},devices:{id:,details:}}}"
```

Comment: well sure, it's dumb, but before the question was edited, it's what was asked.